# Database scaffolding stopped working in .Net Core 1.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-core-1.1

We upgraded our .Net Core 1.0 projects to .Net Core 1.1 and realized that we can no longer scaffold databases in EF Core. Here is the project.json file:

```
 {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.1.0"
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

When the command below is run in PM console, the following error message is generated: Unrecognized option '--build-base-path'

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Googling it was not conclusive. Any workarounds or ways to fix it?

Comment: @Sanket why? what's the merit behind of this solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With .NET Core 1.1 you have to do it on the command line. See following link for the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

I had additionally the problem, that my PATH wasn't correct. I had to add `C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin` because it was missing.

On the command line, go to your project directory and enter

`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=<Your Server>;Database=<Your Database>;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir <Your path for the model classes> --force`

and voila, after a second the sources are generated...

Hope this helps
Klaus